# Is there a PoE (Power over Ethernet) kit available for the 802.11ac Airport Extreme?

Tags: airport

Is there a PoE (Power over Ethernet) kit available for the 802.11ac Airport Extreme? I.e., a kit that will allow me to power the Airport Extreme from PoE instead of from a wall outlet?

Comment: POE doesn't let you power routing hardware, it lets you power downstream hardware, like IP phones, etc.

Comment: @Jason Salaz: AirPort Extreme supported 802.3af, I used them. See: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP55?locale=en_US. The limit isn't routing or not routing, the limit is 15.4 W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the power supply expects 100-240 VAC and lists the current draw as 1.5 A which seems quite high for the heat it puts out, but perhaps with several USB drives connected and max power it gets even half that usage in real life.

You certainly can take DC power from POE [using a splitter](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-POE10R#spec), but those all seem to provide 1A at 12 VDC which is a far cry short of the wattage listed for the Airport Extreme. I doubt you'd find a DC to AC inverter that would generate enough AC to run the Airport though...

Comment: The upper limit of power for 802.3af is 15.4 W. With 150 W (from the Apple technical specification), the AirPort Extreme can't be powered with 802.3af with a splitter. The risk of fire is high.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, see http://find-a-poe.com/wp-content/uploads/WS-GPOE-12v36w1.pdf - works up to 328 ft from a power source.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.